# MS Access: Passing Combo Box values from SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days and can't figure it out.  I have a small Access (2013) database that has a button on a form that writes the contents of some of the fields in the "Students" table to the related (child?) "Lunch" table.  The Click event has the following line of code...

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Lunch (StudentID, DateOfLunch, TypeOfLunch, Cost) SELECT [ID],[TodaysDate],[TodaysLunch]![Column(1)],0 FROM Students"
```

This writes everything except the combobox value TodaysLunch into the `[Students]![TypeOfLunch]` combobox.  I've tried `[value][text]`, etc. but it's always blank. I have both of these combo boxes `[TypeOfLunch][TodaysLunch]` get their data from values from another table, if that means anything.  Access throws no errors, there is just nothing in that field when I check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Lunch (StudentID, DateOfLunch, TypeOfLunch, Cost) 
SELECT [ID],Forms![YourFormName]![TodaysDate],Forms![YourFormName]![TodaysLunch],0
FROM Students
```

Which will insert **all** student records into the lunch table with the selected lunch type & date from your form.

Comment: I tried that and get a "Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query".  It sounds like I have to pass the entire combobox contents including the index (which I thought it was doing by calling the object directly).  The combobox is pulling the data from another table via a lookup which I think is what the problem is.  I changed the destination in the Lunch table field from a combobox to a textbox and still it doesn't work....strange.